# Getting System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException when create new namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am try to define new namespace to be used to create entry behavior as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TK.CustomMap.Sample.TKLoginPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TK.CustomMap.Sample.Behaviors;assembly=TK.CustomMap.Sample">
  <StackLayout Spacing="15" Padding="10,20,10,20">
    <Label Text="Welcome to Trackware" FontSize="25" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
    <Label Text="Your easy way to track" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>

    <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="Email/Mobile Number" FontSize="15" x:Name="user_name" TextChanged="enable_login_btn">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:IsValidValidator x:Name="userNameValidator"/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

    <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Placeholder="PIN/Password" IsPassword="True" FontSize="15" x:Name="password" TextChanged="enable_login_btn">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:IsValidValidator x:Name="passwordValidator"/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Login" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" IsEnabled="False" x:Name="login_btn" Clicked="login_user"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

but when I try to run it I have the following exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.

OnOtherHand, when I remove the namespace declaration and using the project run correctly.

This is my validation Code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TK.CustomMap.Sample.Behaviors
{
    class IsValidValidator : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.Text = "test";
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas please?

Comment: And what's the inner exception?

Comment: what does the code for your validators look like?

Comment: There is no additional messages as inner exception,